# error message AadGroupCreationLimitExceeded when using CreateTeam graph API endpoint in Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I'm using Graph API Create Team endpoint. When I've tested the flow it run successfully, but on the next run I get the following error message:

> {   "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url:
> https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request
> Method: POST, Response Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers:
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\nx-operationid:
> cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e\r\nx-telemetryid:
> 00-cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e-40032a234fdf1740-00\r\nX-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: B7C2163BAF2D4C6D9A8CA7314163BDF4 Ref B: DB3EDGE2617 Ref C:
> 2022-07-13T13:09:47Z\r\nDate: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 13:09:47 GMT\r\n,
> ErrorMessage : {"errors":[{"message":"Error when calling Middle
> Tier. Message: ''. Error code: 'AadGroupCreationLimitExceeded'. Status
> code:
> BadRequest.","errorCode":"Unknown"}],"operationId":"cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e"}",
> "innerError": {
> "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url:
> https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request
> Method: POST, Response Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers:
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\nx-operationid:
> cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e\r\nx-telemetryid:
> 00-cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e-40032a234fdf1740-00\r\nX-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: B7C2163BAF2D4C6D9A8CA7314163BDF4 Ref B: DB3EDGE2617 Ref C:
> 2022-07-13T13:09:47Z\r\nDate: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 13:09:47 GMT\r\n,
> ErrorMessage : {"errors":[{"message":"Error when calling Middle
> Tier. Message: ''. Error code: 'AadGroupCreationLimitExceeded'. Status
> code:
> BadRequest.","errorCode":"Unknown"}],"operationId":"cc9dc27f2daa4a40ae5f6ef6b445951e"}",
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "innerError": {},
> "date": "2022-07-13T13:09:48",
> "request-id": "9e717d71-db05-4a84-a7e0-ef61c027146f",
> "client-request-id": "9e717d71-db05-4a84-a7e0-ef61c027146f"
> }   } }

Anyone knows what AadGroupCreationLimitExceedederror means, and how to solve this?

FYI: I don't have 5,000 groups in Azure to reach the Azure AD organization limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating new teams on behalf of a user or as application? If you are creating new teams on behalf of a user, there is a limit of 250 directory objects/user.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, to be honest. Here is the thing, I have an Azure app that is connected to Graph, inside the app is all permission required for the endpoints. In PA I have a custom connector pointing to the azure app. I'm guessing it is an application? The custom connector connection however is my admin user. Doe that answers your question?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) under **Delegated and application permissions** are the differences between application and delegated permissions explained. If you use "Active Directory OAuth" authentication in Power Automate, then you are using delegated permissions (on behalf of a user).

Comment: The issues was that the scope permissions were delegated instead of application. Thank you @Optimal